# linq to entities if filter parameter is null then select all entities?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Im filtering for entities using an ID but if the ID is null then I want to return all the entities. so in the code below if competitorID is null id like to return all the briefcompetitors.

```
var competitors =
                NeptuneUnitOfWork.Briefs.FindWhere(b => b.ID == briefID)
                                 .Select(b => b.BriefCompetitors.Where(b=>b.ID == competitorID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `SelectMany`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you do it this way:

```
IQueryable<Brief> briefs = NeptuneUnitOfWork.Briefs.Where(b => b.ID == briefID);

if (competitorID != null)
{
    competitors = briefs.Select(b => b.BriefCompetitors.Where(b=>b.ID == competitorID));
}
else
{
    competitors = briefs.Select(b => b.BriefCompetitors);
}
```

Technically you could leave the problem to the SQL Server:

```
// Note the || clause
competitors = briefs.Where(b => b.ID == briefID)
                    .Select(b => b.BriefCompetitors.Where(b=>b.ID == competitorID || competitorID == null));
```

Comment: Im asking for all the briefCompetitotrs to be returned not all the briefs.

Comment: returns an empty list with no results(count is zero).

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor change to @xanatos post

```
// Note the || clause
competitors = briefs.Where(b => b.ID == briefID && (competitorID == null || b.ID == competitorID));
```